# Как узнать прописано ли в manifest category.HOME?

Tags: android, android-manifest

У меня есть несколько манифест файлов под разные сборки, в одном из них активность с `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />`, как мне программно прочитать код манифеста или узнать что там действительно есть `category.HOME`??

Comment: Не проще определить по варианту сборки - вы ведь заранее знаете в каких оно есть? Типа `switch (BuildConfig.FLAVOR) {case "flavorName": .....}`

Comment: @woesss, да, скорее всего так и придется сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно, потому что после создания вашего приложения все конвертируется в APK, и этот манифест больше не доступен для чтения во время выполнения.

Однако вы можете попробовать поискать нужные вам данные в PackageManager.

Comment: копипаст https://stackoverflow.com/a/14395175/13941944

Comment: И? Это запрещено? Человек задал вопрос, не смог найти на него ответ сам по каким-то причинам. Тут половину ответов можно как копипаст отметить. Или вообще закрыть StackOverflow.ru, ведь все уже есть на EN версии. Если мой ответ его не устроит, он может его проигнорировать. Если устроит ему будет плюс и другим кто ищет ответы на ру версии.

Comment: Такие вещи логичнее было бы писать в комментах, нежели позиционировать дословный копипаст без обработки как полноценный ответ.

Comment: Это мой выбор где писать в комментах или нет. Есть ответ, он полноценный (может и не подходящий для конкретного человека, но это уже ему решать ставить галку или нет, ставить + или нет). Если позиционировать, что где-то уже есть ответ, то проще закрыть ру стаковерфлоу

Comment: А еще половина вопросов тут взята с других ресурсов. Так зачем писать вообще ответы? Проще в комментах давать ссылки на статьи/уроки и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Собственно по совету [Sergei Buvaka](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1200770/235964) использовал PackageManager для определения есть ли в приложении активность с `category.HOME`

```
public static boolean isLauncherPackage(Context context) {
    boolean result = false;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```